# Rolling a sphere on a fractal curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, fractals

Given a rectifiable curve C : [0, 1] → **R**<sup>2</sup> in the plane, it makes sense to roll a unit sphere **S**<sup>2</sup> on the plane along that curve and ask what is its net rotation in **SO**(3).

I wonder if this also makes sense for a wider class of curves than just the rectifiable ones.

For simplicity let C : [0, 1] → **R**<sup>2</sup> be a homeomorphism onto its image C([0, 1]), and assume C([0, 1]) has constant Hausdorff dimension d with 1 < d < ∞. (I.e., every neighborhood of every point of C([0, 1]) has the same Hausdorff dimension d.)

Is it possible that, although C([0, 1]) is not rectifiable, it nevertheless makes sense to ask what the net rotation is of a unit sphere rolled along it from beginning to end?

For definiteness, we can consider the "Koch curve" (2nd paragraph of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KochSnowflake.html) that is one-third of the Koch snowflake curve.

Call this Koch curve **W**. **W** is the limit of a sequence of standard stages **W**<sub>n</sub> as n → ∞.

Its Hausdorff dimension is easily computed to be log<sub>3</sub>4 = 1.2618595+. Since this exceeds 1, it cannot be rectifiable.

If net rotation makes sense for this curve, what element of **SO**(3) is it? (Assume that Stage 1, the "witch's hat" of four equal line segments, has euclidean length = 4/3.)

I would be happy to define this concept as the limit as n → ∞ of the net rotation of **S**<sup>2</sup> along the nth stage **W**<sub>n</sub> if that limit exists.

Comment: Isn't it simply like rolling the unit-sphere over a finite number of spikes? I'd rather study the net rotation of a sphere of radius $r$ and see its asymptotic behavior as $r$ goes to $0$. I'm afraid it is well-known, remembering me the popularization of fractals by the question about what is the length of a coast.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "spikes". But when the sphere rolls over **W**_n, even though as n —> oo the length it rolls over —> oo, it seems possible to me that its net rotation approaches a limit in SO(3).

Comment: Could you clarify the notion of "net rotation" in the case of rolling a sphere along a continuous and piecewise smooth arc? What is the result of rolling a sphere (1) along a circle and (2) along a square?

Comment: If we want the sphere to roll continuously along a square (i.e. defining a continuous map $\mathbb S^2\times [a,b]\to\mathbb R^3$, and we want to  keep  its rotation axis fixed along each edge (orthogonal to it), the rotation axis must jump at each corner. But what if we rotate the sphere along a square with corners smoothed in $\epsilon$ disks around the vertices, and take the limit of these smooth paths in $SO(3)$ as $\epsilon\to0$? It seems that the corresponding limit motion of the sphere can't be a continuous map $\mathbb S^2\times [a,b]\to\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Pietro Majer: By net rotation, I just mean the element of SO(3) that takes the initial orientation of the 2-sphere, when it's tangent to the plane at C(0), to its final orientation, when it's tangent to the plane at C(1) (ignoring the translation by the vector C(1) - C(0)).

Comment: Thank you, but what is not clear to me is how does the sphere roll along a continuous, non differentiable  path $\gamma$ (in particular, say, crossing a vertex of a square). In this case, is the “net rotation” defined to be the limit of net rotations wiht a sequence of uniformly convergent smooth paths  $\gamma_j\to\gamma$ ?

Comment: Yes, it's the limit of the net rotations of a sequence of approximating polygons that limit to the (rectifiable) curve.

Comment: Isn't the net rotation independant of the path? Go straight or wiggle between C(0) and C(1), doesn't the sphere end up with the same change of orientation? (Sorry about my comment with spikes - I was letting the sphere dive through the plane !)

Comment: Oh well, forget about it, since rotations in $SO(3)$ don't commute... Your question is then close to quantum concerns when two operators A and B don't commute, as it happens most often. Sometimes we get close formulas involving their commutator [A,B].

Comment: The paths where rolling doesn't make sense might be the paths where you can't integrate $y~dx$ along the path, so the area enclosed is not well-defined. To first order, rolling around a small closed path rotates by the area enclosed times the difference in curvatures between the base space and the rolled space, and if this is not well-defined then I doubt rolling makes sense. The limits of approximating piecewise linear paths would not have to agree.

Comment: I'm expanding a bit on Douglas Zare's take. By the theory of Young differential equations, we know that the net rotation (and more generally the curve traced in $SO_3$, using the continuous topology), which is defined in a natural way for smooth curves, actually is continuous with respect to the $\mathcal C^\alpha$ topology for all $\alpha>1/2$. This gives, by unique continuous extension, a natural definition for the net rotation of any curve that is regular enough. This is enough to deal with the case of the Koch curve, I believe.

Comment: Then for lower $\alpha$, the continuity breaks down (as exemplified by the fact that the integral of $y\,dx$ is not continuous, so this approach does not work anymore. This will always fail when the curve has Hausdorff dimension 2 (it cannot be larger), for instance for the paths of Brownian motion.

Answer (score 1):

Numerically on the Koch curve, it seems to quickly converge. Symbolically, it is tedious to figure out any closed formula. At stage $n$, rolling the unit sphere on the $(x,y)$-plane along $[0,\alpha]\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ with $\alpha=3^{-n}$ rotates it around the $y$-axis with the matrix $A := A(\alpha):=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\alpha&0&\sin\alpha\\0&\;1\;&0\\-\sin\alpha&0&\cos\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. We only need to compose it with the $\beta:=\pi/3$ rotation around the $z$-axis whose matrix is $B:=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\beta&\sin\beta&0\\-\sin\beta&\cos\beta&0\\0&0&\;1\;\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ according to the recurrence
$$R_{n,0} := A(3^{-n})\;,\;\;R_{n,k+1} := R_{n,k}BR_{n,k}B^{-2}R_{n,k}BR_{n,k}\,.$$
The net rotation is $R_{n,n}$. In PARI/GP with 512-bit precision we instantaneously get $R_{100,100} $. Its first 20 decimals digits stabilize starting with $R_{56,56}$. Here they are :
$$\begin{pmatrix} \;\;\;0.54420\,52646\,18151\,51477 &  \;\;\;0.07439\,24346\,27331\,14793 & \;\;\;0.83564\,72914\,04756\,45330\\
-0.07439\,24346\,27331\,14793 & \;\;\;0.99641\,61277\,92991\,15095 & -0.04025\,74955\,03816\,29478\\
-0.83564\,72914\,04756\,45330 & -0.04025\,74955\,03816\,29478 & \;\;\;0.54778\,91368\,25160\,36382\end{pmatrix}$$
Does anybody recognize something there?

**EDITS:**

**1.** I prefixed most transforms by a rotation $B^m$ around the $z$-axis and suffixed them with the inverse rotation $B^{-m}$ so as to keep rolling along the $x$-axis and benefit from repeated calculations. It amounts to look at the oriention of the next straight segment we want to roll the sphere over, rotate the whole plane, curve and sphere together so as the straight segment now looks in the unchanged $x$-direction and orientation, roll, and rotate the whole back.

**2.** What if the limit net rotation depended on the sequence of approximating curves we used? For example the Koch curve can also be approximated "from above" by carving in a roof starting as two line segments of length $1/\sqrt{3}$ at angle $\pm\pi/6$ from the $x$-axis. Fortunately, in that specific example we get the same numerical limit as with the previous calculation. This hints at celebrating the net rotation as a universal property of fractals!

**3.** Here is my PARI-GP code :

```
default(realbitprecision, 512);
R(n,k) = if(!k, A, my(M=R(n,k-1)); M*B*M*B^-2*M*B*M);
f(n) = { \\ Standard approximation by growing a unit segment
  my(a = 3^-n, b = Pi/3); 
  A = [cos(a), 0, sin(a); 0, 1, 0; -sin(a), 0, cos(a)];
  B = [cos(b), sin(b), 0; -sin(b), cos(b), 0; 0, 0, 1];
  R(n,n)
};
g(n) = { \\ Alternative approximation by carving in a roof
  my(a = 3^(-1/2-n), b = -Pi/3, c=Pi/6); 
  A = [cos(a), 0, sin(a); 0, 1, 0; -sin(a), 0, cos(a)];
  B = [cos(b), sin(b), 0; -sin(b), cos(b), 0; 0, 0, 1];
  C = [cos(c), sin(c), 0; -sin(c), cos(c), 0; 0, 0, 1];
  C*R(n,n)*C^-2*R(n,n)*C
};
f(100)
g(100)
```

**4.** To get a closed formula, we may try to describe $R = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}R_{n,n}$ as a fixed point of some transform. Or see how $R$ behaves as the initial unit segment is replaced by a very small segment. Maybe we'll recognize the coefficients in the matrix as a known taylor series in the segment length.

Comment: This is very interesting, but I am a bit confused by why there is any rotation about the z-axis. Every rotation (or infinitesimal rotation) when rolling a sphere along any curve on the xy-plane should be about some axis *parallel to the xy-plane*.

Comment: Okay, I think I see that you're just conjugating a rotation about an axis parallel to the xy-plane with a z-axis rotation to get the appropriate axis rotation. According to my calculation, the angle of this rotation appears to be 0.99535+ radians.

Comment: The matrix entries seem to be exactly equal to ± each other in pairs, ignoring the (2,2) entry ... except for the (1,1) and (3,3) entries, which are merely pretty close rather than ±equal.  Strange.

Comment: If (1,1) = A and (3,3) = A+B, then (2,2) = 1-B

Comment: @DanielAsimov I agree with $0.99535+$ radians $\mod 2\pi$, with an axis in the $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0.99606+\\0.08867+\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ direction, almost $y$. Was its zero $x$-component expected? It is zero too for the finite iterations $R_{1,1}, R_{2,2}, \dots$.